# Power BI API request 405 Method not Allowed Error

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to connect my API using Bearer Token  to power bi but I've got ( API request 405 Method not Allowed Error ):

[image]

But, using postman I can connect successfully:
[image]

The parameters that I'am using are:

URL: https://www.rhid.com.br/v2/report.svc/apuracao_ponto
Authorization : Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.jZbZmRZKAIuJeDl_QEeOqeQS3Q5qwkXSKlUqCFlPLhQ

Content-type: application/json

Someone could help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: I hope that is not the real bearer token?

Comment: What are your settings for accessing the content? To my knowledge, it should typically be set to "Anonymous".

Comment: Also, is this working on Postman?